# custom field in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my /app/views/institution/_form.html.erb I have

```
<%= f.textfield :auto_complete_list %>
```

Which gets its data from /app/models/institution.rb

```
  def auto_complete_list
    return self.county.city.name + ' '+ self.county.name
  end
```

But I don't want this to be submitted when the button is pressed.
My current solution is to delete it from params[:institution]
Is there a cleaner approach to removing read-only attributes from submit parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I agree with daekrist's answer, you can easily keep this out of `params[:institution]` by using the lower level form helper methods that:

```
<%= form_for @institution do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= text_field_tag 'auto_complete_list', @institution.auto_complete_list %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

So now when the form is submitted, it will be in `params[:auto_complete_list]` instead of `params[:institution][:auto_complete_list]`.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, a cleaner approach will be to never put things like this in your forms :)

If you want autocomplete, it would be better to use some js/jquery plugin and attach it to the field you need.

Comment: I am using jquery autocomplete, but things have gotten complicated. I didn't want to get the value within the textbox, but the ID associated to it which I placed into a hidden field. But I still had to show the text within a textbox, and that was part of the form. 

Now that I placed it into another params hash variable, everything is fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to try token fields, it is well explained here http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields